# How to virtually change the pageview in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/):

But in my real code, I've used google tag manager to manage google analytics. So I have just one script in the head of my website which belongs to gtm:

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-P8F58CT');

ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto'); // Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined
```

As you can see, I've added `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto')` right after that google tag manager (the same as the tutorial I've linked in the first line of my question). And I have a `ga('send', 'pageview', newURL);` code which will be executed when the page changes using ajax.

The problem is it throws: (as I've commented in code above)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

How can I fix it? Someone told me no need to add `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto');` at all, and gtm will handle it all. **But** in my tests:

- When I open my website (homepage), and run `ga('send', 'pageview', "/adv");` in the console, nothing changes in google analytics and it still points to the homepage.
- When I open my website (homepage), and run `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto');` and then run `ga('send', 'pageview', "/adv");`, then the google analytics will be changed to the `/adv` (not homepage anymore). So I believe `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto');` is needed. But why it is undefined?

Comment: Does your GTM container already include GA tracking? Is there a reason you're not sending the virtual page views using GTM?

Answer (score -1):

You have Google Tag Manager snippet on your page. Not the Google Analytics’ analytics.js. You are confusing the two.

You shouldn't have this or anything related to ga() on the page.

```
ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto'); // Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined
```